# Extract Sketch file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unzip, jszip

The purpose is to extract the contents of a `.sketch` file.

I have a file with the name myfile.sketch. On renaming the file extension to myfile.zip and extracting the same in Finder, I'm able view the files within. I tried doing the same on the server using Node.js by renaming the file extension to `.zip`. I wasn't able to extract the files, rather I got some ZIP files within the files.

```
var oldPath = __dirname+'/uploads/myfile.sketch',
newPath = __dirname+'/uploads/myfile.zip';

fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
console.log('rename callback ', err);
});
```

Is it possible to extract a non-ZIP file using frameworks like [JSzip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)?

Comment: Just to confirm I understand right, you're asking about how to read the contents that are inside of a `.sketch` file? Isn't a `.sketch` file an image-based format?

Comment: .sketch file has a package of contents in it.. folders, images and json files within it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `.sketch` file is essentially a ZIP file, the extension does not matter. Any tool that is capable of unpacking a ZIP file will work.

You can verify this with the `file` command:

```
$ file myfile.sketch
myfile.sketch: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

As you are working on the server already, there is nothing stopping you from just using the OS's command line tools like [`unzip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip).

Like this:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function unzip() {
  const filename = 'myfile.sketch'
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('unzip ' + filename);
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
}

unzip();
```

Doing it with JSZip is straight-forward as well:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var JSZip = require('jszip');

new JSZip.external.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  fs.readFile('myfile.sketch', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      reject(e);
    } else {
      resolve(data);
    }
  });
}).then(function (data) {
  return JSZip.loadAsync(data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks this works.. where should I mention the directory for the file to be extracted? Now I have the files extracted to the root folder :(

Comment: You can get all command line options by either running `unzip -h` or `man unzip`. The argument you are looking for is `-d`.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @herrbischoff I am tyring your `jsZip` solution to extract the Sketch file, but I am not sure where to output it's unzipped/extracted content. I have see the `jsZip` official API but can't find how to finally output the final content. I can see the bugger output however in console when do `console.log()`, but don't know how to output it to any folder.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan: `fs.write()` / `fs.writeFile()`?